# codeigniter google login with existing gmail account creating duplicate row

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-api

I have implemented google login in existing user table in coeigniter. User can login whether with existing email and password or from google login. Everything working fine but i need to check with existing email. Suppose that gmail already in the database i need to update the oauth_provider and oauth_uid in the existing row. Right now creating new row for google login. So my emails are  duplicated.

public function checkUser($data = array()){

```
    $this->db->select('id');
    $this->db->from($this->tableName);
    
    $con = array(
        'oauth_provider' => $data['oauth_provider'],
        'oauth_uid' => $data['oauth_uid']
    );
    $this->db->where($con);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    //echo $this->db->last_query(); die;
    
    $check = $query->num_rows();
    if($check > 0){
        // Get prev user data
  $result = $query->row_array();
        
        
        // Update user data
        $data['edited_dt'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $update = $this->db->update($this->tableName, $data, array('id' => $result['id']));
        
        // Get user ID
        $userID = $result['id'];
    }else{
        // Insert user data
        $data['created_dt'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $data['edited_dt'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $insert = $this->db->insert($this->tableName, $data);
        
        // Get user ID
        $userID = $this->db->insert_id();
    }
    
    // Return user ID
    return $userID?$userID:false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code above you are not checking if the email already exists in your database. What you are doing is just finding against `oauth_provider` and `oauth_uid` if record is found you are updating that record which is fine. But when it's the first time user login using gmail, it won't find any record so it will create a new record, now here before creating new record you need to check if current email already exists you need to update the existing record else create new record.

**your insert code**

```
}else{
    // Insert user data
    $data['created_dt'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $data['edited_dt'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $insert = $this->db->insert($this->tableName, $data);
    
    // Get user ID
    $userID = $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

**Note:** Make sure you edit the column name and code according to your database design.

**Corrected insert code**

```
}else{
    
    //check if email already exist
    $this->db->select('id');
    $this->db->from($this->tableName);
    
    $con = array(
        'email' => $data['email']
    );
    $this->db->where($con);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    
    $check = $query->num_rows();
    
    if($check > 0){
        // Get prev user data
        $result = $query->row_array();
        
        // Update user data
        
        //here update whatever data you want to update for that record
        $data['edited_dt'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $update = $this->db->update($this->tableName, $data, array('id' => $result['id']));
        
        // Get user ID
        $userID = $result['id'];

    }else{
        //Insert new record            
        
        // Insert user data
        $data['created_dt'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $data['edited_dt'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $insert = $this->db->insert($this->tableName, $data);
        
        // Get user ID
        $userID = $this->db->insert_id();
    }
}
```